# How to create a Token using alg: A128KW and enc:A128CBC-HS256 in C# with jose-jwt library

Tags: c#, encryption, jwt, token, decode

I'm totally new in the world of JWT. I'm using the library jose-jwt in C#.
I wrote the following code to get the token:

1. I declared the payload as a Dictionary
2. I declared the key as a JSON
3. I encrypted the payload and the secretKey

   ```
        var payload = new Dictionary<string, object>()
        {
            { "sub", "mr.x@contoso.com" },
            { "exp", 1300819380 }
        };

        var json = @"{
            ""kty"":""oct"",
            ""use"":""sig"",
            ""k"":""GawgguFyGrWKav7AX4VKUg""
        }";

        var secretKey = Jwk.FromJson(json, JWT.DefaultSettings.JsonMapper);


        string token = Jose.JWT.Encode(payload, secretKey.OctKey(), JweAlgorithm.A128KW, JweEncryption.A128CBC_HS256);
   ```

I got the following token: *eyJhbGciOiJBMTI4S1ciLCJlbmMiOiJBMTI4Q0JDLUhTMjU2In0.y3NP9hx4zYmLnpab0tDVZNJ2q5aAG6BpUnMhEn11a7z903J4___LtQ.IRgLnbwqjH6m702g4Hn6QA.XCYICPsoG1dVYmEi-Nu0a4w9yzDm9__xDYT1IsxxLaZEa_tSHSJo9Ai2Ym5aN_Sw.bfH7yGqpopEwrT_O1aD1rA*

When I try to decode the token on [jwt.io](https://jwt.io) I get the following result:
[jwt.io decoded token image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMtdn.png)

There's something wrong in the signature (even though I used the same in the code) and the payload is an uncomprensible string with special chars.

Thanks to anyone who will be able to help me.

Comment: What is your intention? You created an [encrypted token](https://github.com/dvsekhvalnov/jose-jwt#creating-encrypted-tokens) (JWE) but seem to be surprised that the token is encrypted, so maybe you just wanted the usual signed token (JWT/JWS)? And jwt.io can't deal with JWE, it only supports the normal signed tokens.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, it is right I have an encrypted token, since I have to send that token to an http request, the server will use that token in order to authenticate the client request and get access to an exposed API. I probably misunderstood the jwt.io functionality. I apologize if I wrote any inaccuracies, I'm trying to deal with a world totally new for me.

Comment: no problem, I just wanted to clarifiy.  Jwt.io can indeed only handle signed tokens (3 segments (header.payload.signature) but not the 5 segment JWE. And  I also don't know any other online tool that can handle JWE tokens. So you have to write your own decrypt/decode/verify tool for testing.